# How can I split 2 columns of cells with multiple lines into unique rows, keeping/duplicating the surrounding data?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working with a sheet that has 2 columns with cells that may have multiple rows in the cell.  I'm trying to figure out how to split both cells at the same time (as they both should have the same number of lines in them) and maintain/duplicate the surrounding data for each new split.  I've seen a few different ways to accomplish this using both a formula and a script, seen below, but those all seem to hinge on only splitting a single column of cells, not 2 columns.

My data set is below and it's pulling information from a Forms submission, so I'm not able to change how the data is input, I just need to try and figure out the best way to parse the data.  Ideally, both cells will have the same lines and will be split on a carriage return (I'm most familiar with CHAR(10) being used) and I just need to figure out splitting both simultaneously.  I put together some example data in the sheet linked below.  I've also included one example of code that I've found that performs this task on a single column of cells (from [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/123876/split-multi-line-comma-separated-cell-into-new-rows-duplicate-surrounding-ro), but is quite old -- I'm also not quite sure how to modify my range to not be column B in the example)

```
function result(range) {
  var output2 = [];
  for(var i=0, iLen=range.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    var s = range[i][1].split("\n");    
    for(var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      var output1 = []; 
      for(var k=0, kLen=range[0].length; k<kLen; k++) {
        if(k == 1) {
          output1.push(s[j]);
        } else {
          output1.push(range[i][k]);
        }
      }
      output2.push(output1);
    }    
  }
  return output2;
}
```

Data sample available here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1edR-pKxx98l01zFE2LBUkWvQJPKQ9IV_LIHieDwf-1I/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about if use formula?

Comment: Using a formula would probably be preferred... really whichever runs faster as it's a fairly large data set.

Comment: If so, please look at my formula in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to achieve to convert from `RAW DATA` to `DESIRED RESULT` in your shared Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using the custom function.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Sample script:

When your shared Spreadsheet is used, please put the formula of `=result(A3:E6)` to a cell.

```
function result(values) {
  return values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    var [colD, colE] = e.slice(-2).map(function(f) {
      return f.split("\n").map(function(g) {return g.split(/\s+/)[1] || g});
    });
    return ar.concat(colD.map(function(f, j) {return e.slice(0, 3).concat([f, colE[j]])}));
  }, []);
}
```

- At first, the values of column "D" and "E" are splitted.
- As the next step, each row is created from the splitted values.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- This sample script can be used for your sample Spreadsheet. If the format of the values are changed, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

### Added:

From your 2nd shared Spreadsheet, I prepared the script for converting from `RAW DATA` to `DESIRED RESULT`. I thought that the column "D" is different from 1st shared Spreadsheet in your 2nd shared Spreadsheet. In this case, `"1  email1@sample.com\n2  email2@sample.com\n3 email3@sample.com"` is required to be converted to `Bill`, `Steve` and `Ted`. But this cannot be done. So I prepared the following sample script using your 1st logic. It's like `email1@sample.com`, `email2@sample.com` and `email3@sample.com`.

#### Sample script:

In order to use this script, please put `=result(A3:O6)` to a cell.

```
function result(values) {
  return values.reduce(function(ar, e) {
    var head = e.splice(0, 3);
    var [colD, colE] = e.splice(0, 2).map(function(f) {return f.split("\n").map(function(g) {return g.split(/\s+/)[1] || g})});
    var values = colD.map(function(f, j) {return head.concat([f, colE[j]]).concat(e)});
    return ar.concat(values);
  }, []);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I've put this in and tried to run it, but it's giving me an error that "TypeError: f.split is not a function"

Comment: Apologies, that may have been on me... I realized my sample data set wasn't representative enough, as my data actually goes from A:O and is currently about 2000 lines.  I changed my formula to only include columns A:E and it gave me results.  Is there an easy way to adjust the script out to include the additional columns?  Thank you!

Comment: @Tommy Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to modify the script, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? I would like to modify it by correctly understanding about your situation. Of course, please remove your personal information. Can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect?

Comment: Here is a link to a sample sheet with raw data and the desired output.  The only variance is that my actual data is ~2000 lines and will be expanding with form inputs.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17pCmJZ56bFeZnY2oLx5v7NezZWadUew6179pwml__o4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Tommy Thank you for adding the information. From your 2nd Spreadsheet, I prepared the sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Apologies, I was out for the weekend, but I'll give that a try today.  Thank you!

Comment: that seems to work great!  Thank you so much!  If you have a minute are you able to give a quick breakdown on how it works?  If not, no problem.  I have a base knowledge of scripts but I'm not great at them yet.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Tommy Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About the explanation of script, in this case, I separate 3 parts for each row. For example, it's "A1:C1", "D1:E1" and "F1:O1". And split the values of "D1:E1". And merge them with "A1:C1" and "F1:O1". I used `reduce()`, `map()`, `split()` and `concat()` for this. You can see the documents of them at "References" section. If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet227');
  var osh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet222');
  osh.clearContents();
  var hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var rg=sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var n=0;
  for(var i=0;i+n<vA.length;i++) {
    var dA=vA[i+n][3].split('\n');
    var eA=vA[i+n][4].split('\n');
    if(dA.length>1) {
      for(var j=0;j<dA.length;j++)  {
        var nr=[vA[i+n][0],vA[i+n][1],vA[i+n][2],dA[j],eA[j]];
        vA.splice(i+n++,0,nr);
      }
      vA.splice(i+n--,1);
    }
  }
  vA.unshift(hA);
  osh.getRange(1,1,vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I answered this on Reddit?

https://reddit.app.link/uGOAxYRcg3

Matt

Answer (score 1):

With formula:

```
={ arrayformula(
   vlookup(
     transpose(
       split(
         textjoin(
           ",",true,
           filter(regexreplace(row(D3:D) & regexreplace(D3:D,"[^\" & char(10) &
                  "]",""),"[" & char(10) & "]","," & 
                  row(D3:D)),D3:D<>""
           )
         ),",",true,false
       )
     ),{row(A3:A),A3:D},{2,3,4},false)
   ),
   transpose(
     split(
       textjoin(
         "," ,true,
         filter(
           regexreplace( D3:D,"[\" & CHAR(10) & "]","," ),D3:D<>""
         )
       ),",",true,false
     )
   ),
   transpose(
    split(
      textjoin(
        "," ,true,
        filter(
          regexreplace( E3:E,"[\" & CHAR(10) & "]","," )
          ,E3:E<>""
        )
      ),",",true,false
    )
  )
}
```